# How to set SO_RCVTIMEO option only for read and not for accept in C

Tags: c, sockets, timeout, recv

I have written a C server with multithreaded architecture. The server loops on `accept()` to accept incoming connections and creates a new thread for each one to `read()`.

I would like the server to make the `read()` fail after a set amount of time if no messages are received, but if I try this:

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 10;
tv.tv_usec = 0;

setsockopt(listener_socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv)
```

My `accept()` times out, too.

Can I set the `SO_RCVTIMEO` option to just make the `read()` time out? Or, is there a way to solve the problem without changing the entire multi-threaded structure of the application?

Comment: Err, don't set it on the listening socket?

Comment: @user207421 I answered my own question specifying that that was the problem. I didn't think of it immediately because I saw another guy having problems with this approach

Comment: AFAIK, `SO_RCVTIMEO` does not apply to `accept()`, only to `recv/from()` and `read()`. The only way to timeout `accept()` is to put the listening socket into non-blocking mode and then use `select()` or `(e)poll()`.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it by using

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 10;
tv.tv_usec = 0;

setsockopt(client_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv)
```

in the client thread on the newly spawned socket, instead of using it on the listener socket directly.